# In ngx-agora, webrtc not supported in any browser

Tags: javascript, angular, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Please Could you help me for solving my problem.I am using the **ngx-agora package** in ***angular 10+ version*** that package is working fine before 1 month but now it's creating the issue.

Whenever we try to make a video/audio call or try to join into a room for video/audio call, we get an error **This browser doesn't support webRTC.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because of a recent update with Chrome browsers. You will need to update to the latest version of the Agora Web SDK. Since you are using the open-source community NGX wrapper, you will want to use [Agora Web v3.6.10](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/release_web_video?platform=Web#v3610), don't use 4.x because it has breaking changes to the API that will cause issues when used in the Angular/NGX wrapper.

[Agora SDK Downloads Page](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/downloads?platform=Web)
[3.6.10 Release Notes](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/release_web_video?platform=Web#v3610)

Comment: Thanks using latest build of sdk worked for me

Comment: Can you please help me about the video controls. I am not able to fetch the controls to pause video and enable/disable the camera during video call.

Comment: The video stream is live so there isn't a concept of pausing the video, but you can control mute/unMute the video. use the `this.localStream.` to get the local stream. use `muteVideo` to disable the camera https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#mutevideo and use `unMuteVideo` to enable https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#unmutevideo

Comment: @Nikitagarg did this information help you? or do you have any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

Use
AgoraSDK 3.6.10
but my suggestion is to upgrade your code to agora4.
[AgoraSDK3.6.10](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/agora-rtc-sdk@3.6.10/AgoraRTCSDK.min.js)

Comment: Thanks using Agora SDK 3.6.10 worked for me

Comment: my pleasure....

Comment: Can you please help me about the video controls. I am not able to fetch the controls to pause video and enable/disable the camera during video call.

Comment: Hello @Nikitagarg,
Sorry, I'm too late to reply on this. have you fixed the issue?